# How can I prove that derivations in Chomsky Normal Form require 2n - 1 steps?

Tags: grammar, theory, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I'm trying to prove the following:

> If G is a Context Free Grammar in the Chomsky Normal Form, then for any string w belongs L(G) of length n ≥ 1, it requires exactly 2n-1 steps to make any derivation of w.

How would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 16):

As a hint - since every production in Chomsky Normal Form either has the form

> S → AB, for nonterminals A and B, or the form
>
> S → x, for terminal x,

Then deriving a string would work in the following way:

- Create a string of exactly n nonterminals, then
- Expand each nonterminal out to a single terminal.

Applying productions of the first form will increase the number of nonterminals from k to k + 1, since you replace one nonterminal (-1) with two nonterminals (+2) for a net gain of +1 nonterminal.  Since your start with one nonterminal, this means you need to do n - 1 productions of the first form.  You then need n more of the second form to convert the nonterminals to terminals, giving a total of n + (n - 1) = 2n - 1 productions.

To show that you need *exactly* this many, I would suggest doing a proof by contradiction and showing that you can't do it with any more or any fewer.  As a hint, try counting the number of productions of each type that are made and showing that if it isn't 2n - 1, either the string is too short, or you will still have nonterminals remaining.

Hope this helps!

Comment: :Could you tell why do we need to do n-1 productions of the first form.

Comment: Sure! Each terminal in the resulting string is eventually formed by taking a nonterminal and expanding it to a terminal via some production of the form A -> a. This means that there have to, at some point, be a total of n nonterminals produced. One of them comes for free from the start symbol. Each time you do a production of the form A -> BC, you get one more nonterminal. Therefore, you need to do n-1 productions of the form A -> BC so that you can create the n-1 additionally-needed nonterminals.

Comment: :Oh do you mean to say that the '-1' of the expression 'n-1' comes since one of them comes for free from the start symbol?

Comment: @justin Yep, exactly.

Comment: :Oh sorry but I couldn't get that.Do you mean to say that we're not adding the _start_ symbol production to the stack.Let me show you an example.Let's say the productions are S -> AB ,A -> Amount,B -> Unit,Amount -> [0..9] ,Unit -> $.I could see that we could reach 50$ with 5 steps which is true for the expression '2n-1' where n=3.Aren't we adding the _start_ symbol production to the stack here?